# SQL SELECT LIKE (Insensitive casing)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, case-insensitive

I am trying to execute the sql query:

```
select * from table where column like '%value%';
```

But the data is saved as 'Value' ( V is capital ).

When I execute this query i don't get any rows. 
How do i make the call such that, it looks for 'value' irrespective of the casing of the characters ?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

use LOWER Function in both (column and search word(s)). Doing it so, you assure that the even if in the query is something like %VaLuE%, it wont matter

```
select qt.*
from query_table qt
where LOWER(column_name) LIKE LOWER('%vAlUe%');
```

Answer (score 21):

If you want this column be case insensitive :

```
ALTER TABLE `schema`.`table` 
CHANGE COLUMN `column` `column` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Thus, you don't have to change your query.

And the MySQL engine will process your query quicker than using lower() function or any other tricks.

And I'm not sure that using lower function will be a good solution for **index searching performance**.

Answer (score 15):

Either use a [case-insensitive collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) on your table, or [force the values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) to be lower case, e.g.

```
WHERE lower(column) LIKE lower('%value%');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try using a case insensitive collation

```
select * from table
where column like '%value%' collate utf8_general_ci
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `lower()` function:

```
select t.*
from table t
where lower(column) like '%value%';
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using PostgreSQL, a simpler solution is to use [insensitive like (ILIKE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column ILIKE '%value%'
```

Answer (score 6):

you should use either **lower** or **upper** function to ignore the case while you are searching for some field using like.

```
select * from student where upper(sname) like 'S%';
```

OR

```
select * from student where lower(sname) like 'S%';
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question, but I'm posting this for posterity:
Non-binary string comparisons (including `LIKE`) are case-insensitive by default in MySql:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

This will eventually do the same thing. The ILIKE works, irrespective of the casing nature

SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE column_name ILIKE "%value%"

Comment: There is no ILIKE in mysql, my guess that is a Postgre query.

Comment: But this is the same as the answer [already done here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853452/sql-select-like-insensitive-casing/44121586#44121586) four years ago. I dont' see something valuable that hasn't been told in the other answer.