# How I get data in using LIKE without differentiating between uppercase And lowercase?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get names using `Like '%BEJO%'`, but no record is found because my data in database is `'Bejo'`.

How I do I get the name `'Bejo'` with `LIKE '%BEJO%'`? (case insensitive)

Comment: It depends on which collation you're working on. Some collations are case-insensitive (e.g. `utf8-general-ci`), while some others are not.

Comment: Please try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853452/sql-select-like-insensitive-casing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where LOWER(column_name) LIKE LOWER('%BEJO%');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the collation of that column is case-sensitive. If you want it to always be case-insensitive, then change its collation to the one that ends with `ci`. If you want to keep it the way it is and only make the query case-insensitive, then you can change the collation in the query. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE name LIKE '%BEJO%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Alternatively, you can simply change the case of both sides using `LOWER()` or `UPPER()`. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE UPPER(name) LIKE UPPER('%BEJO%');
```